# Variance Between Facebook Comments count and what actually retrieved from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I own a page and I'm trying to fetch comments on each post. On Facebook page itself I can see the count value is 137 as per below Image

[image]

When I've tried to retrieve those comments using graph API I got 89 only. Where did this variance came from? I'm calling the comments endpoint using page access token. I shall see every comment, even the private comments as well.

Comment: Comments by some users who have disabled all API access, might not show. But the numbers in this instance make it rather unlikely, that it would be this many. Give us proper information, how exactly you fetched/got this number - did you ask for the summary, or are you just paging through the comments that get returned? Whether you are looking at only top-level or all comments, might also result in a difference.

Comment: @CBroe I retrieve comments using both summary to get the count and apply pagination on comments endpoint to retrieve comment text itself, and both gives the same count (89). Also I apply stream filter to retrieve all comments.